# Number of spanning tree in a grid graph

Tags: tree, spanning-tree

I'm having some issue trying to solve this problem:
How many different spanning trees does the (grid graph) M 2,4 have?

Can someone explain me how to find this number?

(I didn't see Kirchhoff theorem or Matrix tree in class so I shouldn't use them)

Thanks

Comment: Possibly related: [Caley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)

Comment: Caley's formula works just for complete connected graphs